# How to create condition inside the datasnapshot/recyclerview in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, database, firebase-realtime-database

I created tabbed activity for my project. I have three tabs which are Paid , Unpaid and Item Posted
I want to classify every of them based on the status. I have created the coding but I'm not sure on how to implement the method inside my coding. I want only order that have "PAID" as their status will be shown up inside my PaidFrag.

PaidFrag:

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Order");

databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            orderList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot orderSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : orderSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Order order = ds.getValue(Order.class);
                    if (order.getStatus().equals("UNPAID")) ;
                    orderList.add(ds.getValue(Order.class));

                }
            }

            psOrderAdapter PsOrderAdapter = new psOrderAdapter(orderList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(PsOrderAdapter);
        }
    }
```

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, final int i) {

    myViewHolder.name.setText("Name : " + orderList.get(i).getName());
    myViewHolder.status.setText("Status : " + orderList.get(i).getStatus());
    myViewHolder.total.setText("Total Price : RM " + orderList.get(i).getTotal());
    myViewHolder.address.setText("Address : " + orderList.get(i).getAddress());
    myViewHolder.dateTime.setText("Order ID  :" + orderList.get(i).getOrder_id());

    myViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String cust_id = orderList.get(i).getCust_id();
            String oid = orderList.get(i).getOrder_id();
            String status = orderList.get(i).getStatus();
            String courier = orderList.get(i).getCourier();
            String track = orderList.get(i).getTrackingNum();
            String num = orderList.get(i).getPhone();

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, updateStatus.class);
            intent.putExtra("cust_id",cust_id);
            intent.putExtra("order_id",oid);
            intent.putExtra("status",status);
            intent.putExtra("courier", courier);
            intent.putExtra("trackingNum",track);
            intent.putExtra("phone",num);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for a Firebase Database query, which limits what nodes are returns from the database:

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Order");
Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("status").equalTo("PAID");
query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  ...
```

You'll need to make sure that the `status` and `PAID` strings match the exact key and value that you have in your database.

For more on this, see the Firebase documentation on [ordering and filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data).

Comment: Exactly where you now have the code that creates the `databaseReference` and call `addValueEventListener` on it.